# Interactive charts in PDF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf

I want to generate interactive charts in PDF just like [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/)

but this is for embedding on web page I want to embed interactive chart in PDF. any help?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, I think it's unlikely that the PDF format is going to support this.

Comment: @Gian actually it might be possible to do this using adobe-javascript embedded in the PDF file, but it is not going to be an easy task, and it will not be supported by many PDF viewers.

Comment: any API which helps in making such kind of pdf?

Comment: @Gian You'd be surprised what PDF is capable of... e. g. executing Javascript, opening sockets and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You specified Java, so I would say iText has some [partial support for writing adobe-javascript actions](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=278). You must be aware that latest versions of itext uses AGPL license, so you must pay a commercial license if you want to use this in a commercial closed-source application.

Another option is to use [Adobe Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/downloads.html), but I am not sure if you will be able to use it from Java.

You may also find this link useful: [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Guide - Adobe](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331649757370&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf&ei=xlxfT9SgL4nr0gGt-OW0Bw&usg=AFQjCNHHreMDZltpH7-RrZr4HjP3891GeQ)

This feature of the PDF specification (I mean embedded javascript) is not commonly used, so it might be a bit difficult to find start-up information and sample code.

[Here you will find a few examples of interactive PDFs](http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/MicroStation/Interactive+3D+PDF.htm) that use javascript, there is even an example of a [flying helicopter in 3D](ftp://ftp2.bentley.com/dist/collateral/Web/Building.pdf), (it actually moves around while viewing the file).